# Add more than one hyperlink in a MS-Word table cell

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm new to the Word programming with C# and I'm trying to insert 3 hyperlinks in a word document using C#, but for some reason, the hyperlink get overwrite and only the last hyperlinks remains in the cell.

After some research, it seems to be a common problem. Using this exemple, it *should* work...   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c35d9598-e933-4a90-ba6e-088c2bdb6484/adding-multiple-links-to-a-table-cell?forum=worddev

Here's my function

```
private static void RemplirSommaireChangement(Word.Document doc, Word.Table t, string noChangement, string responsable, DateTime dateMEP, List<string> backlogItems)
{
    int nbRows = t.Rows.Count;
    Word.Range r;
    object oAdress;
    Word.Hyperlinks hl;

    t.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Text = noChangement;
    t.Rows[2].Cells[2].Range.Text = responsable;
    t.Rows[3].Cells[2].Range.Text = dateMEP.ToShortDateString();

    t.Rows[5].Cells[2].Range.Text = "";
    hl = t.Rows[5].Cells[2].Range.Hyperlinks;

    foreach (string s in backlogItems)
    {
        r = t.Rows[5].Cells[2].Range;
        oAdress = "http://www.test-" + s + ".com";
        r  = r.Hyperlinks.Add(r, oAdress, TextToDisplay: (object)(s + "\r\n")).Range;
        r.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
        r.InsertAfter("\r\n");
        r.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

    }
}
```

and how it is call :

```
    List<string> stories = new List<string>();
    stories.Add("test1");
    stories.Add("test2");
    stories.Add("test3");

    RemplirSommaireChangement(doc, t, "No changement", "responsable", DateTime.Now, stories);
```

Any idea what's wrong with this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is I think that you have

```
r = t.Rows[5].Cells[2].Range;
```

*inside* your `foreach` loop, which means that you are resetting the range `r` To be the range of the *cell* for each string in `backlogItems`. So you will end up with a hyperlink constructed from the last of those strings, followed by a couple of paragraph returns.

Moving that line so it comes before the loop is where I’d start. Without testing I can’t tell whether you would need to adjust other parts of the code as well.

Comment: oh! you're right..... so much time spent for this.... arggh.... Thank you!